# How to add SonarQube Plugin in Build.Gradle and take the reports of current project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-2.0

I tried downloading SonarQube and followed each steps based on this link, [SonarQube Setup and add SonarQube plugins in build.gradle](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/integrating-and-understanding-sonarqube-in-android/)

Was able to execute SonarQube from Command but while I am adding the plugins of SonarCube in Build.Gradle it is showing an error like this when I tried to sync a project,

Error#25: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script

But I have added a plugin and properties of SonarQube in build.gradle,

```
plugins {
id "org.sonarqube" version "7.2.1"
}
```

and adding properties of SonarQube,

```
sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "MyApplication2"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "SQKey"
    property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
    property "sonar.language","java"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
}}
```

Android Studio Version is, 3.1.3 and
Gradle Version is, 4.4 
and, downloaded SonarQube Version is, 7.2.1

My Question here is, Is SonarQube 7.2.1 not compatible for Gradle Version 4.4?

Please see the Image below (SonarQube is Up) in command Prompt,
[image: SonarQube up in command prompt]

Any idea regarding how to generate the reports of my currrent project using sonarqube and executing a command in cmd prompt?

**Error # 33: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed**

Please find the below build.gradle file,

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"



repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

plugins {
id "org.sonarqube" version "7.2.1"
}
sonarqube{
properties{
    property "sonar.projectName", "Example 16-8"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "example 16-6-key"
    property "sonar.sources","src/com.example.project"
    property "sonar.language","java"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", 
    "build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
    //        property "sonar.exclusions", "src/main/java/com/foo/Foo.java"
    }}
    allprojects {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    }
    }
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    }
```

What mistake I am doing here in above build.gradle file and how to run sonarQube and generate the reports of my current project?

And, please find the below Image - When I add http://localhost:9000/ in my browser, it does not show any of my Android Projects. Please refer this Image for reference how SonarQube islooking in my browser,

[image: When I add http://localhost:9000/ in my browser, it does not show any of my Android Projects. Please refer this Image how does sonarqube looks in my browser,]

Tried to create Gradle.properties file to add this lines,

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.login=admin
systemProp.sonar.password=admin
```

Opened Android Studio Terminal and executed this,
    .\gradlew sonarqube

**Please see below Image, I am getting Sonar Qube Exception when I tried to execute the command on Android Studio Terminal (Bottom).**

[image: I am getting Sonar Qube Exception when I tried to execute the command on Terminal.]

Comment: Could you share a little more of your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: @ToYonos - Any Suggestions please?

Comment: The buildscript block must be the first one at the top of the file

Comment: @ToYonos - Tried by putting buildscript block in a top most part of build.gradle file. But still, I am unable to analyse or generate bugs report using SonarQube.
Please any suggestion or help?

Comment: @Achiever : is your script valid after you moved buildscript block at the top (is gradle able to parse it)? or do you have some remaining errors when trying to execute some tasks?

Answer (score 3):

The error #33 you get comes from the strict syntax that must be followed when using plugins{} block, which is described in Gradle documentation here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html  (see "Strict syntax" section)
In your build.gradle script, you have added the "plugins{}" block after some other directives, which is not allowed.
I guess the other error #25 comes from the same reason.

You should try to rewrite your script and move the 'buildscript' block first, then the 'plugins' block, and then other parts of your scripts

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonar-url"
    property "sonar.login", "login - token "

    property "sonar.projectName", "hello-world-service"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "hello-world-service"

    property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "$buildDir/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
    property "sonar.junit.reportPaths", "$buildDir/test-results/test/"
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/xmldefs/**,**/spec/api.json"
    property "sonar.cpd.exclusions", ", **/persistence/entity/**"
    property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
    property "sonar.clover.reportPaths", "**/build/clover/clover.xml"
    property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "clover"
    property "sonar.sources", "src/main/kotlin"
    property "sonar.tests", "."
    property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
    }
  }

// Build should fail if coverage less than minimum.
jacocoTestCoverageVerification.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
build.finalizedBy jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

// Add this in your build.gradle